# Javascript to filter nodes in XML

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm using a javascript to read a XML and print a particular node in HTML which is working fine with the below code.

I'm looking to filter the nodes based on the language of the url.

For example I want to show output like this

```
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_applications.asp?**lang=en**
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/apps.asp?**lang=en**
```

This is the XML i'm trying to read. Currently with the below JS its printing all the  nodes in the HTML file, I would like to filter and show the URLs only that has lang=en in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<bookstore xmls="http://www.google.com/sitemap.0.9">
   <book category="">
       <loc>http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_applications.asp?**lang=en**</loc> 
    </book>
    <book category="">
       <loc>http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_applications.asp?lang=fr</loc> 
    </book>
    <book category="">
       <loc>http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_applications.asp?lang=de</loc> 
    </book>
    <book category="">
       <loc>http://www.w3schools.com/xml/apps.asp?**lang=en**</loc> 
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

The JS that prints all  nodes and output in HTML

```
<script>
var xhttp;
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "writers.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var x, i, txt, xmlDoc; 
    xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    txt = "";
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("loc");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

Can you please provide any pointers to filter the URLs with a match condition?

Is it correct approach to use

```
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    if('txt'.indexOf('lang=en')) {

        txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
    }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if one string contains another substring in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: In addition to simply looping over the elements, using the technique cited by @Justinas to find if the value contains the string you're looking for, you could also use [XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript). Depending on how many nodes you have, browser support, etc., just looping through them and checking the value could be faster.

Comment: @Justinas Mike McCaughan
i'm trying to use the below. Can you tell me if thats the correct approach?
 
   ` for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
 if('txt'.indexOf('lang=en')) {
    

 
        txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
    }
 
 }`

Comment: Not quite, since that code tests if the literal string "txt" contains "lang=en", which of course it doesn't. You want to test if `x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue` contains "lang=en". Also, you'll want to check that `indexOf()` does not return `-1`.